# How to preserve user input in UITableViewCell before dequeue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm creating an application in which I need the users to fill out a number of inputs in a `UITableViewCell`, kinda like a form. When the user taps on the done button, I need to collect those inputs so I can run some calculations and output them on another view controller

Here is the method I used to collect those inputs:

```
func doneButtonTapped() {

    var dict = [String: Any]()

    for rows in 0...TableViewCells.getTableViewCell(ceilingType: node.ceilingSelected, moduleType: node.moduleSelected).count {

        let ip = IndexPath(row: rows, section: 0)

        let cells = tableView.cellForRow(at: ip)

        if let numericCell = cells as? NumericInputTableViewCell {

            if let text = numericCell.userInputTextField.text {

                dict[numericCell.numericTitleLabel.text!] = text
            }

        } else if let booleanCell = cells as? BooleanInputTableViewCell {

            let booleanSelection = booleanCell.booleanToggleSwitch.isOn
            dict[booleanCell.booleanTitleLabel.text!] = booleanSelection
        }
    }

    let calculator = Calculator(userInputDictionary: dict, ceiling_type: node.ceilingSelected)
}
```

The problem I'm having is when the cell is out of view, the user's input is cleared from the memory. Here are two screenshots to illustrate my point:

[image]

As you can see, when all the cells appears, the done button managed to store all the inputs from the user, evidently from the console print. However, if the cells are out of view, the inputs from area/m2 are set to nil:

[image]

The solution that came to mind was I shouldn't use a dequeue-able cell as I do want the cell to be in memory when it is out-of-view, but many of the stackover community strong against this practice. How should I solve this problem? Thanks!

***UPDATE***

Code for `cellForRow(at: IndexPath)`

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        guard let node = node else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

        let cellArray = TableViewCells.getTableViewCell(ceilingType: node.ceilingSelected, moduleType: node.moduleSelected)

        switch cellArray[indexPath.row].cellType {

        case .numericInput :

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "numericCell", for: indexPath) as! NumericInputTableViewCell
            cell.numericTitleLabel.text = cellArray[indexPath.row].title
            return cell

        case .booleanInput :

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "booleanCell", for: indexPath) as! BooleanInputTableViewCell
            cell.booleanTitleLabel.text = cellArray[indexPath.row].title
            return cell

        }
    }
}
```

My two custom cells

`NumericInputTableViewCell`

```
class NumericInputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var numericTitleLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var userInputTextField: UITextField!

}
```

`BooleanInputTableViewCell`

```
class BooleanInputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var booleanTitleLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var booleanToggleSwitch: UISwitch!

}
```

Any takers?

Comment: Why don't you fill you dictionary while user is filling it ? Then you have all data stored in your dictionary instead of in your table (which is not recommended)

Comment: Use the delegate to pass the data back to dict (your data source). Because cells are being reused, you don't want to depend on the display data on the cell.

Comment: Agree with @GIJOW.  Said another way, a view shouldn't be used as a substitute for a data model.

Comment: You can just generate and register a different reuseidenfitifer for each cell, this will ensure the same cell is dequeued the next time around. Also just make sure that the cell logic doesn’t refresh the cell if you set the same content when it is being dequeued

Comment: @GIJOW I tried that in `didSelectRow` and that didn't work, that would mean the input can only be stored when the user is NOT tapping on the text field, this is so because tapping on the text field directly, the text field will be the first to respond instead of registering the tap

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks, interesting, how am I substituting for a data model?

Comment: @HMHero Thanks, that might be solution, can you please elaborate more? thanks

Comment: have a look on this, maybe can be helpful https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXForms

Comment: What I mean is....  A data model is something that you expect will preserve your data until you need to use it.  That's kind of what you're doing with the view if it's the only place the data exists until you collect it on "done" being pressed.

Comment: @BrendonCheung Can you post codes for tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) and one of your custom cell?

Comment: thanks, and that is exactly the problem, how do I store the data else where so I can preserve those store when the cells are dequeued. I tried it in `didSelectRow` method but it turned out it doesn't work

Comment: @HMHero, please see update, thanks

Comment: @BrendonCheung added my test code. hope you get an idea.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other contributors. The cells should not be used for data storage. You should consider another approach (like the one [HMHero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1272833/hmhero) suggests).

But, as your question was also about how to access a UITableViewCell before it is removed, there is a method in **UITableViewDelegate** that you can use for that:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // do something with the cell before it gets deallocated
}
```

This method tells the delegate that the specified cell was removed from the table. So it gives a last chance to do something with that cell before it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Because of table view reuses its cells, usually, it's not a good idea if your data depends on some components from the table view cell. Rather, it should be the other way around. Your table view data always drive it's table view cell's component even before any user input data is provided in your case.

- Initial Data - your should already have somewhere in your code. I created my own from your provided code

  ```
      let data = CellData()
      data.title = "Troffer Light Fittin"
      data.value = false

      let data2 = CellData()
      data2.title = "Length Drop"
      data2.value = "0"

      cellData.append(data)
      cellData.append(data2)
  ```
- Example

  ```
  enum CellType {
      case numericInput, booleanInput
  }

  class CellData {
      var title: String?
      var value: Any?

      var cellType: CellType {
          if let _ = value as? Bool {
              return .booleanInput
          } else {
              return .numericInput
          }
      }
      }

  protocol DataCellDelegate: class {
      func didChangeCellData(_ cell: UITableViewCell)
  }

  class DataTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
      var data: CellData?
      weak var delegate: DataCellDelegate?
  }

  class NumericInputTableViewCell: DataTableViewCell {

  let userInputTextField: UITextField = UITextField()

  override var data: CellData? {
      didSet {
          textLabel?.text = data?.title
          if let value = data?.value as? String {
              userInputTextField.text = value
          }
      }
  }

  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
      super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

      userInputTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
      contentView.addSubview(userInputTextField)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  func textDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
      //update data and let the delegate know data is updated
      data?.value = textField.text
      delegate?.didChangeCellData(self)
  }
  //Disregard this part
  override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()
      textLabel?.frame.size.height = bounds.size.height / 2
      userInputTextField.frame = CGRect(x: (textLabel?.frame.origin.x ?? 10), y: bounds.size.height / 2, width: bounds.size.width - (textLabel?.frame.origin.x ?? 10), height: bounds.size.height / 2)
  }
  }

  class BooleanInputTableViewCell: DataTableViewCell {

  override var data: CellData? {
      didSet {
          textLabel?.text = data?.title
          if let value = data?.value as? Bool {
              booleanToggleSwitch.isOn = value
          }
      }
  }

  let booleanToggleSwitch = UISwitch(frame: .zero)

  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
      super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

      booleanToggleSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggled), for: .valueChanged)
      booleanToggleSwitch.isOn = true
      accessoryView = booleanToggleSwitch
      accessoryType = .none
      selectionStyle = .none

  }

  func toggled() {
      //update data and let the delegate know data is updated
      data?.value = booleanToggleSwitch.isOn
      delegate?.didChangeCellData(self)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
  }
  ```
- In View Controller, you should update your original data source so when you scroll the table view, the data source privide right infomation.

  ```
  func didChangeCellData(_ cell: UITableViewCell) {
      if let cell = cell as? DataTableViewCell {
          for data in cellData {
              if let title = data.title, let titlePassed = cell.data?.title, title == titlePassed {
                      data.value = cell.data?.value
              }
          }
      }

      for data in cellData {
          print("\(data.title) \(data.value)")
      }
  }



  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          return cellData.count
      }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let data = cellData[indexPath.row]
      let cell: DataTableViewCell
      if data.cellType == .booleanInput {
          cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(BooleanInputTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as! BooleanInputTableViewCell
      } else {
          cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(NumericInputTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as! NumericInputTableViewCell
      }
      cell.data = cellData[indexPath.row]
      cell.delegate = self
      return cell
  }
  ```

In short, try to have a single data source for table view and use the delegate to pass the updated data in the cell back to the data source.

Please disregard anything that has to do with layout. I didn't use the storyboard to test your requirements.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for this!! let me try it out and get back!!very much appreciate you effort in helping me!

Comment: I am in the process of implementing your approach, one question through, when my view controller conforms to the protocol, where do I set the delegate to `self`? in the `cellForRow` method? thanks

Comment: In my example, yes.